# Javascript files not loading in sources

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome

So I have a landing page up at http://mytestosteronekit.com.  Im using Leadpages to create the page.  I have an index.html file that pulls in the leadpage with script in the head.  I am also including bootstrap CSS, a custom stylesheet for style overrides, bootstrap JS, and a custom JS file.  The css links are loading just fine and work on the page.  Mainly have this for the navbar.  But the js files are not firing and I can't figure out why.

I have them included right before the closing body tag.  They show while inspecting, but they don't load in the sources.  I was using relative url paths originally but switched to an absolute path just for security.  Still no go.

I need this navbar to be working on mobile, please help me!

Comment: is there any error on browser console?

Comment: Yes I figured it out. I forgot to load in jquery before loading in bootstrap and my custom js.  Silly..

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap requires jQuery to be loaded before firing.  All I needed to do to fix this problem was call to jQuery before calling the other scripts.  Problem solved.  No interference with Leadpages scripts.

Answer (score 0):

Try put `<script>` tags lines before the closing tag `</body>`. I did it for you below:

```
<html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Custom CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/style.css">
    <meta name="leadpages-meta-id" content="144ccecf3f72a2:1696aa1f6b46dc" /><meta name="leadpages-serving-domain" content="https://crawfordobrien.leadpages.co" /><meta name="leadpages-served-by" content="html" />
</head>

<body>
    <script src="http://mytestosteronekit.com/js/bootstrap.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="http://mytestosteronekit.com/js/custom.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <!-- Leadpage -->
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://my.leadpages.net/template/load-144cc5ec6639c5-1696a36f6639c5-dnoeNG8gtnHtHMXGoqpWmbNBhgtazHED.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```